# Simple Xamarin app build goes frozen state visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin, and trying to build my first app with it using visual studio 2015,
 here is the tutorial I'm following: [Xamarin - First Application](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xamarin/xamarin_first_application.htm)

However, when I try to build/rebuild the project, it seems to goes in frozen state. it's continuously running(rebuilding), not sure about the time limit.
I'm frustrating now.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here is my log:

```
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]:                  Looking for Java 6 SDK..
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\CurrentVersion found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6\JavaHome not found.
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.7\JavaHome found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55).
[I:]:                     Found Android SDK. API levels: 19, 21, 23
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[D:]:                     Tracking avd started
[D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\hina\.android\avd'
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: ZY222VBJ9L   device
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
[D:RunShellCommand]:      ZY222VBJ9L getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      ZY222VBJ9L getprop
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 1 devices
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: ZY222VBJ9L   offline
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: ZY222VBJ9L   device
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
[D:RunShellCommand]:      ZY222VBJ9L getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      ZY222VBJ9L getprop
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: ZY222VBJ9L   offline
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: ZY222VBJ9L   device
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
[D:RunShellCommand]:      ZY222VBJ9L getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      ZY222VBJ9L getprop
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Try checking the Xamarin & Xamarin.Diagnostics output window in VS for diagnostics messages. Try to check if there are errors of if there is a process which is getting stuck.

Comment: @degant: From where I can find Xamarin.Diagnostics in VS? I'm using community version BTW

Comment: Your **output** window should have a dropdown with these options. The same dropdown that has options for Build, Debug, General etc.

Comment: Thank you so much!@degant I've added log to the question.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything wrong with this log. You might have to check few other windows too. The app isn't building for you right? So what does the build window say? Does it have an error message?

Comment: @degant: Nope, It doesn't have any error message! Yes, not building up.

Comment: Every once in a while that happens to me when debugging.  Usually I just cancel the build and try to run it again and it works.

Comment: @KenTucker, May be in your case, In my case I'm not able to cancel the build, I've to forcefully quit VS from task manager.

Answer (score 0):

try to set ANDROID_HOME path once in your environment variable and then restart it.

Comment: Thanks, will give a try and let you know!